# Bibliography using the combine class

Tags: natbib, combine

I am using the `book` option of the `combine` class. When I format the following example, the citations typeset as `[0,0]` instead of `[1,2]`. The bibliography items all begin with zero. I did not import a file in my posted example, but the same thing happens to imported files. I would like a solution to this problem.

```
\documentclass[book]{combine}
\usepackage[numbers]{combnat}
\begin{document}
\title{The collection}
\author{A. N. Editor}
\date{\today}
\maketitle
\tableofcontents
\chapter{First chapter}
\section{Introduction}
Chapter citations: \cite{article01, article02}.
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\begin{thebibliography}{2}
  \providecommand{\natexlab}[1]{#1}
  \providecommand{\url}[1]{\texttt{#1}}
  \expandafter\ifx\csname urlstyle\endcsname\relax
  \providecommand{\doi}[1]{doi: #1}\else
  \providecommand{\doi}{doi: \begingroup \urlstyle{rm}\Url}\fi
  \bibitem[Name(1986)]{article01}
  Author Name.
  \newblock My article.
  \newblock \emph{Mathematics}, 1986.

  \bibitem[Two(1987)]{article02}
  Author Two.
  \newblock Another article.
  \newblock \emph{Statistics}, 1987.
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Well, it seems that `combnat`'s compatibility with `natbib` is far from perfect. You have to use numbers as labels for `\bibitem`s (e.g. `\bibitem[1]{article01}`). Otherwise simply load `natbib` instead of `combnat`.

Comment: Using labels is a problem because my document contains several bibliographies. natbib does not work with imported files. Originally, I used comcite, which also required some modifications to get sorted citations in imported files. However, the book option caused the chapter heading to change to BIBLIOGRAPHY. This heading continued until the next chapter, which presented a problem if I had two or more articles in a chapter. I used the sectionbib option of natbib to help eliminate this problem. I should also mention that combnat works fine if I do not use the numbers option, which I must use.

Comment: @TomPrice I was able to use the comcite package by modifying the \thebibliography environment.

Answer (score 3):

This is a workaround.

The package `combnat` redefines the command `\@lbibitem` in a way that seems incompatible with the `numbers` options.

So we first load `natbib` with the `numbers` option and save the meaning of `\@lbibitem`

```
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\makeatletter
\let\old@lbibitem\@lbibitem
\makeatother
```

Then we load `combnat` with the `numbers` option and restore the meaning of `\@lbibitem`

```
\usepackage[numbers]{combnat}
\makeatletter 
\let\@lbibitem\old@lbibitem
\makeatother
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass[book]{combine}
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\makeatletter
\let\old@lbibitem\@lbibitem
\makeatother

\usepackage[numbers]{combnat}
\makeatletter 
\let\@lbibitem\old@lbibitem
\makeatother


\begin{document}
\title{The collection}
\author{A. N. Editor}
\date{\today}
\maketitle
\tableofcontents
\chapter{First chapter}
\section{Introduction}
Chapter citations: \cite{article01, article02}.
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\begin{thebibliography}{2}
  \providecommand{\natexlab}[1]{#1}
  \providecommand{\url}[1]{\texttt{#1}}
  \expandafter\ifx\csname urlstyle\endcsname\relax
  \providecommand{\doi}[1]{doi: #1}\else
  \providecommand{\doi}{doi: \begingroup \urlstyle{rm}\Url}\fi
  \bibitem[Name(1986)]{article01}
  Author Name.
  \newblock My article.
  \newblock \emph{Mathematics}, 1986.

  \bibitem[Two(1987)]{article02}
  Author Two.
  \newblock Another article.
  \newblock \emph{Statistics}, 1987.
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

Output (citations):

[image]

Output (bibliography):

[image]

Comment: Your solution worked but the sort&compress option of combnat fails as it did with the combcite package. I suspect modifications to combnat similar to those I mentioned in my previous comment would correct this. I decided to use the modified combcite package.